# Checking to see if today is in the scheduled day utilizing a binary mapping table in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am pulling XML data from a 3rd party application using SQL Server 2008 (which I only have read-only access to the DB) and it stores the day or days of the week a job is supposed to run in one of those XML fields.

SQL uses a recursive day code of Sunday=1, Monday=2, Tuesday=4, Wednesday=8, Thursday=16, Friday=32, Saturday=64.

I am pulling the day from this XML field like the following.

```
case 
   when (job.SJDefn.value('(schedules/schedule/name)[1]', 'varchar(30)') ) like '%Week%' 
      then job.SJDefn.value('(/schedules/schedule/recurring/date/week/day_of_week)[1]', 'int') 
   else 0 
end as JDOW,
```

I was originally utilizing the this to determine the current date of the week as but the values were obviously not compatible.

```
DATEPART(dw, getdate()) AS CDOW, -- Sun 1 Mon 2 Tue 3 Wed 4 Thu 5 Fri 6 Sat 7`
```

So I moved to:

```
case DATEPART(dw, getdate())
   when 1 then 1        -- Sunday (1=1)
   when 2 then 2        -- Monday (2=2)
   when 3 then 4        -- Tueday (3=4
   when 4 then 8        -- Wednesday (4=8)
   when 5 then 16       -- Thursday (5=16)
   when 6 then 32       -- Friday (6=32)
   when 7 then 64       -- Saturday (7=64)
   else NULL 
end as CDOW,
```

The challenge is that it is an easy translation when the job just runs one day of a week.. but what about Monday/Wednesday/Friday well that is 42 which is an aggregate of the days Monday (2) + Wednesdays (8) + Friday (32).

I could translate this [to text like in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606751/convert-integer-to-a-list-of-week-days?rq=1) and do a string compare to a temp table but that seems inefficient.

I know that there is a [table that can be built like this code](https://sqlcodesnippets.com/tag/freq_interval/) to build a comparison table and I've checked the [SQL Server Agent documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-start-job-transact-sql) (which this isn't but it is quite similar.

It seems like all possible combinations for Sunday - Saturday are basically a bitmap ranged from 1-127.. such as 42 = 0010 1010 which could be an on/off values for each day (first position always 0, 127 = 0111 111) and with that.

```
Position 1 = Always 0    ; binary 0000 0000
Position 2 = Sunday 1    ; binary 0000 0001
Position 3 = Monday 2    ; binary 0000 0010
Position 4 = Tueday 4    ; binary 0000 0100
Position 5 = Wednesday 8 ; binary 0000 1000
Position 6 = Thursday 16 ; binary 0001 0000
Position 7 = Friday 32   ; binary 0010 0000
Position 8 = Saturday 64 ; binary 0100 0000
```

I am thinking about how to potentially use a [bitwise `&` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-and-transact-sql) but it compares the entire bit for an exact match and not a single position as I understand it so not thinking it will accomplish exactly what I want.

What I want is if the current day is in the schedule I get a true / false result from the comparison. I don’t care about interpreting the values into plain English.. For example if the string was 0011 1110 (Monday - Friday), then if the current day value is the equivalent of 0000 0010 (Monday) I be get true. If it was Sunday (0000 0001) it would be false if the reference was that 0010 1110.

I would really think there is a much simpler way of simply checking if the current day falls into the configuration in a few lines vs. building a temporary table to compare against.

**So my question**: given the information above, is there a simple function / query that I can execute to compare the two and return a boolean result (0/1 or Y/N) if the the current day matches the schedule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you a 1/0 result for the current date given a schedule bitmap:

```
declare @Today as Date = GetDate();
-- Assuming that   @@DateFirst   is correctly set:
declare @DoW as Int = DatePart( weekday, @Today );
-- Shift a bit to the appropriate position.
declare @Mask as Int = Power( 2, @DoW - 1 );

-- Sample schedule bitmap.
declare @Schedule as Int = 42;
-- Sign   is used to convert the result of the bitwise-and to a 0 or 1.
--   Any positive value, indicating the corresponding bit is set, will return 1.
--   If there is no match, the result will be zero.
select @Today as Today, @DoW as Dow, @Mask as Mask, @Schedule as Schedule,
  Sign( @Schedule & @Mask ) as IsScheduledToday;
```

As a professor once said, "you're always off by one in this business." It may need a tweak, but should be close.

Comment: Thanks I think this may work like it is.. I'm getting a few odd results I need to track down and I don't completely follow why this works but seems to be on the right track.. let me test it a bit more next week and I'll likely accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to tell exactly what you're trying to do here.  You've explained the problem, but didn't provide any desired output.  Since you have read-only access, however, I assume you're only interested in querying the data.

However, if you have an integer like `42`, and you want to test bitwise if the bit for Monday is set (that is, 2's place), then you do this:

```
42 & 2 = 2
```

If you want to display days of the week you could do something like:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN JDOW & 1  = 1  THEN 'U' ELSE '' END
    + CASE WHEN JDOW & 2  = 2  THEN 'M' ELSE '' END
    + CASE WHEN JDOW & 4  = 4  THEN 'T' ELSE '' END
    + CASE WHEN JDOW & 8  = 8  THEN 'W' ELSE '' END
    + CASE WHEN JDOW & 16 = 16 THEN 'R' ELSE '' END
    + CASE WHEN JDOW & 32 = 32 THEN 'F' ELSE '' END
    + CASE WHEN JDOW & 64 = 64 THEN 'S' ELSE '' END AS scheduled_days
FROM (VALUES (42),(84),(96), (4)) UnnamedTable (JDOW)
```

If you want you could create another table:

```
CREATE TABLE BitwiseWeekDay (
    code tinyint primary key not null,
    day_name nvarchar(10) not null,
    day_short_name nvarchar(4) not null,
    day_code nvarchar(1) not null
)

INSERT INTO BitwiseWeekDay VALUES
(1,'Sunday','Sun','U'),
(2,'Monday','Mon','M'),
(4,'Tuesday','Tue','T'),
(8,'Wednesday','Wed','W'),
(16,'Thurday','Thur','R'),
(32,'Friday','Fri','F'),
(64,'Saturday','Sat','U')

SELECT u.JDOW, 
    b.code,
    b.day_name
FROM (VALUES (42),(84),(96), (4)) u (JDOW) 
    INNER JOIN BitwiseWeekDay b
        ON  u.JDOW & b.code = b.code
 ORDER BY u.JDOW, b.code
```

But, I don't really know what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry I thought I was clear what my desired outcome is.. I added an example.